# Tate conjecture for Abelian varieties without polarizations

Tags: abelian-varieties

I'm reading [Levin's note](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/mordellsem/Notes/L19.pdf) to learn the Tate conjecture for Abelian varieties over number fields. It seems that [Tate's original paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01404549.pdf?pdf=button) and this note both use a weak finiteness hypothesis

> There are infinitely many $B_n=A/G_n$ which are isomorphic, where $A\to B_n$ is an isogeny and all $B_n$ are equipped with polarizations.

I have understood that by considering the maximal isotropic subspace we can prove the key projective lemma

> (Projection Lemma) **Assume that $A$ has a polarization $\theta$**.Let $W\subset V_\ell(A)$ be a $G_K$-stable subspace. Then, there exists a
> operator $u\in{\rm End}(A)\otimes Q_\ell$ such that $u^2=u$ and $uV_\ell(A)=W$.

But I don't know why this holds for Abelian varieties without polarizations. I found that in [this note](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Emurayama/Mordell.pdf) $\S$ 8.2.3 the author avoid the maximal isotropic subspace by proving that the finiteness hypothesis holds without assuming any polarized condition.

If I want to follow the first line, how do I reduce to the polarized cases?

---

I noticed that when we do the reduction

> The map
> $${\rm Hom}(A, B)\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p\to{\rm Hom}(V_p(A),V_p(B))^{G_K}\quad(1)$$
> is an isomorphism if and only if
> $${\rm End}(A)\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p\to{\rm End}(V_p(A))^{G_K}\quad(2)$$
> is an isomorphism.

We actually prove a by-product that if $(2)$ holds for $A\times B$, then it holds for $A$ and $B$, right? Thus if $(2)$ holds for polarized Abelian varieties $C=A^4\times(A^\vee)^4$ (it seems that this holds if the projective lemma holds for $C$ and $C^2$), then we can deduce the Tate conjecture for general Abelian varieties $A$. This method seems to work but we do not get the general result for projective lemma.